# Connecting to a localhost postgres database from within a docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, networking

I have a linux postgres database running on my localhost at port 5432. The IP of my machines network card is 192.168.68.80. My configuration files for postgres look as so:

#### /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

#### /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
```

Now I want to connect to this database from a Node application running inside a docker container. This is what my environment variables file looks like when loading into Node:

#### .env

```
PGHOST=localhost // Host of the postgres db server
PGPORT=5432 // Port of the postgres db
```

After this setup, I build my docker image using my docker file. I then try to run the dockerfile as a container with the following command on linux:

```
sudo docker run --network="host" --env-file .env -p 3000:3000 repo:tag
```

and the app begins to run, and listens for connections on port 3000. But whenever I try to connect  to the app, the app fails to connect to the postgres database server and gives the following error:

```
/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:172
                reject(new sequelizeErrors.ConnectionRefusedError(err));
                       ^

ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Client._connectionCallback (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:172:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorEvent (/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432
  },
  original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432
  }
}
```

I can not figure out why the connection is being refused as it seems like it should be able to connect.

## EDIT:

My current ip tables in case that helps:

```
user$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 1):

docker has its own network within the container. When you say **"PGHOST=localhost"**, it will connect to docker container's internal localhost (which has no relation with your machine localhost), not your machine localhost. You have to put a same network in which your docker and machine is running. It can be your network IP. You can get the IP by giving command **"ip a"** in linux. In my case my wifi is the common network, which ip is **"192.168.X.X/24"** giving **"192.168.X.X"** instead of **"localhost"** will work for me.

Comment: If I pass the argument --network="host", shouldn't that make Docker point to my localhost as well? Is that not the correct use of that docker run argument?

Comment: Also I changed PGHOST=192.168.68.80, the IP of my machine's network card, and am still getting a connection refused.

Comment: Can you try with --network=host. I just tried with my app. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

From a container, the IP address of the host machine is 172.17.0.1. So you should connect to `172.17.0.1:5432`.

Comment: When I change PGHOST=172.17.0.1, I still get the same connection refused error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.1:5432.

Comment: @nick2225 Ye.. I've seen a lot of folks point to that solution, but I'm also getting a refused connection. The postgres is set up by default (0.0.0.0:5432  5432/tcp), so it shouldnt be something within postgres that refuses the gateway. :/